# Memory leak with valgrind, where can I free my pointer

Tags: c

in this portion I have a memory leak of 5 blocks which seems to match my loop turns so I tried adding free(newcw); in the while loop but I get a segmentation fault 11 error (but a clean valgrind), I don't understand why.

```
while(...){
      cword *newcw = malloc(sizeof *newcw);
      if (newcw == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** Error: Not enough memory.\n");
        ...
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      newcw->nbocc = 1;
      newcw->iscommon = 0;
      if (hashtable_add(ht, s, newcw) == NULL) {
        ...
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      /*-----free(newcw);-----*/
}
```

cword is a structure with two members nbocc and iscommon.
Without the free instruction it works (with a memory leak), so I don't know where can I free the  cword structure pointer newcw

Comment: Make sure you are freeing before each return statement in branches where the `malloc` was successful.  (e.g. You may need one before your second `return` in this example.)

Comment: Right before `return EXIT_FAILURE` you should free as well. You can't (or atleast, you don't want to) exit the function without freeing everything you need

Comment: Yes you're right I need to put it before return EXIT_FAILURE,and it works (because it doesn't fail in my test :)) but when I put it after too (for the cases where it doesn't fail) I get a segmentation fault...

Comment: The only reason I can figure out for the segfault is that, in case of successful `hashtable_add` the structure `newcw` is used/freed later. The other users are right when they say that the free should be performed in case of failure as well, but the the cause of the leak is probably some other function you are not showing us.